Using WiX 3.11 to create installer that installs different modules that may be uninstalled as a whole
I have been using a WiX installer project that basically bundles installers from other projects in Visual Studio 2022. I want to change this behavior and have the installer install everything from a single bundle.wxs or product.wxs.
Do I use a  or  ?
Are each of the "modules" to install encapsulated in a  or a ?
I am not an expert WiX by any means, but have put together a bootstrap bundle installer. I want to get away from this so that all of the modules are installed and may be uninstalled as a whole and that the individual parts are not visible in Windows Add/Remove programs.
I must use WiX v3 and not any other installers like InstallShield, etc.
I guess I am not sure of the order of the different WiX sections.
I have tried the following order
<Wix>
    <Bundle>
        <BootstrapperApplicationRef>
            ....
        </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

        <Chain>
            <Fragment>
                .... module 1
            </Fragment>

            <Fragment>
                .... module 2
            </Fragment>

        </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>

I get errors saying the Bundle element contains an unexpected child element 'Fragment'
A Bundle element must have at least one child element of type Chain


The code you shown has a closing Fragment tag missing the closing >, please check.

This is just a boilerplate section. Yes I see that I forgot the closing > on module 1.
